# Manter as divs de conversa do chat quando se muda de página

Tags: javascript

Boas comunidade.

Eu tenho um sistema de chat, como o do fb. Estou a utilizar js, ajax e php. Tudo certo até aqui. Funciona. O único problema agora é que eu queria guardar as divs atuais de chat quando se muda de página.

Como poderei fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Bem isso é um grande problema, tive um parecido só que no meu caso era um player de áudio, onde deveria trocar de página sem pausa o som, procurei muito como [FRAMES](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) que se tornou obsoleto no HTML5 e [IFRAME](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) que é ainda válido pro HTML5, você pode começar por esses dois dependendo da sua necessidade resolva.

Porém para mim a solução que achei foi transformar o meu sistema todo em DOM, ou seja cada pedaço do sistema viro um bloco que era carregado dinamicamente conforma a necessidade e o bloco do player era mantido estático.

No meu caso eu criei um framework próprio em JavaScript para isso, alias o [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) usa um sistema parecido, não sei se já percebeu mas as vezes o video ou os conteúdos e comentários trocam fora de ordem, isso ocorre porque ele é feito dessa forma cada parte do sistema é um bloco independente.

Eles liberaram o framework deles a um tempo atrás, eles o chamam de SPF (Structured Page Fragments), caso tenha vontade e queria usá-lo segue os links:

- [SPF (Structured Page Fragments)](http://youtube.github.io/spfjs/)
- [GIT SPF](https://github.com/youtube/spfjs)

**Estático: renderiza tudo**
[image: Estático renderiza tudo]

**Dinâmico: somente o elemento.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alias sua dúvida esta como PHP mas o correto seria HTML/JavaScript. De qualquer forma espero ter dado uma luz, de como começar.